# Illegal Invocation while passing data attribute on Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, typeerror

I am trying to get the data attribute of a button with id delete_btn and send it through ajax. As a result, I am getting the following error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**

**JQuery**

```
var id = $( "#delete_btn").attr('data-identifier');

$.ajax({

    dataType: "json",
    url: apiURL,
    data: { 'req': 'delete', 'id': id},

    success: function(data){
        //   do something

    },
    error: function (textStatus){
        //do something
    }

});
```

I have even tried getting the attribute value by

```
 $( "#delete_btn" ).data( "identifier")
```

But got the same error

Comment: try this: data: {'req':delete,'id':id}, //

Comment: delete is not a variable. It is a callback function in the api.

Comment: @RahulGopi, also, `delete` is a reserved keyword. Without quotes, it would through an error.

Comment: `console.log(id);` What does it show?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **processData: false** in ajax settings like this

```
$.ajax({
url : base_url+'index.php',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: data,
cache : false,
processData: false
}).done(function(response) {
alert(response);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've seen this answer on SO. But this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this four attribute to your ajax call:

```
async: false,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

Hope this help!